# i wannt to hide some images from my mobile version not from desktop verion of responsive html website

Tags: java, html, css

[I want to hide our product images from mobile version](http://www.razorwires.in/css/main.css)

This is my css :

Web site : http://www.razorwires.in

Comment: Please look here :-

@media only screen and (max-width:535px){
.image { display:none; }
}

Comment: Please take a tour of the help center to see how to ask a good question.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Also please [read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

you can use media query for this thing

but here I suggest to use [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) 
when someone uses touch screen device it detect and add "touch" class to your html tag, then u can hide ur images like below code

```
html.touch .hideimg{
  display: none;
}
```

this will hide on touch device

```
<img src="" class="hideimg" />
```

this will not

```
<img src="" />
```